REGEX allow all chars except (*)
I would like to grab this one
**string**

from the content below
**Perbaiki dan Persiapkan Rumah**: Sebelum mengiklankan rumah, saya melakukan perbaikan kecil yang diperlukan, seperti mengecat dinding,
mengganti **lampu yang rusak**, dan merapikan taman. Penampilan rumah
sangat penting. Membuat rumah terlihat bersih dan terawat bisa menarik
lebih banyak perhatian.

Things i've done so far
(\*\*(?:[A-z]|[0-9]|[\s|\-|\:])+\*\*)

Its working but I need it more simpler like allowing all chars except the asterix (*) which is our parameter.

You can try: \*\*[^*]+\*\*

You can use:
\*\*([^*]+)\*\*

This basically matches 2 asterisks front and back then excludes asterisk and match everything else and capture it.
Check out here: https://regex101.com/r/dMAsyp/2
